# format symbol $" in PowerShell For C# code

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to convert the C# code of the link below to PowerShell code, and I can't process the C# symbol【 $" 】 in PowerShell.

https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/docs/Drawing.md

**All related files:**
https://www.upload.ee/files/12630601/File.zip.html
[image]

Console prompt error:

```
ERROR: Exception calling "Format" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."
Adding Text To Existing Image.ps1 (15, 1): ERROR: At Line: 15 char: 1
ERROR: + $caption = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage([string]::format("capti ...
ERROR: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
ERROR:
```

- Buggy code line for PS:

  ```
  $caption = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage([string]::format("$caption:{$textToWrite}"), $readSettings)
  ```
- Source code line for C#:

  ```
  using (var caption = new MagickImage($"caption:{textToWrite}", readSettings))
  ```

Powershell Code:

```
Add-Type -Path ".\Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU.dll"

$image = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage logo.png
$pathToBackgroundImage = "bg.jpg";
$pathToNewImage = "img_ok.png";
$textToWrite = "Insert This Text Into Image";
$readSettings = New-Object -TypeName ImageMagick.MagickReadSettings
$readSettings.Font = "Calibri"
$readSettings.TextGravity = "Center"
$readSettings.BackgroundColor = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickColor("Transparent")
$readSettings.Height = 250
$readSettings.Width = 680

$image = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage($pathToBackgroundImage)
$caption = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage([string]::format("caption:{$textToWrite}"), $readSettings)

$image.Composite($caption, 590, 450, [ImageMagick.CompositeOperator]::Over)
$image.Write($pathToNewImage)
$image.Dispose()
```

C# source code:

```cs
var pathToBackgroundImage = "path/to/background.png";
var pathToNewImage = "path/to/newImage.png";
var textToWrite = "Insert This Text Into Image";

// These settings will create a new caption
// which automatically resizes the text to best
// fit within the box.

var readSettings = new MagickReadSettings
{
    Font = "Calibri",
    TextGravity = Gravity.Center,
    BackgroundColor = MagickColors.Transparent,
    Height = 250, // height of text box
    Width = 680 // width of text box
};

using (var image = new MagickImage(pathToBackgroundImage))
{
    using (var caption = new MagickImage($"caption:{textToWrite}", readSettings))
    {
        // Add the caption layer on top of the background image
        // at position 590,450
        image.Composite(caption, 590, 450, CompositeOperator.Over);

        image.Write(pathToNewImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: $caption = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage([string]::format("$caption:{$textToWrite}"), $readSettings)
  you are trying to define a variable...but in the constructor reference that same variable...that doesnt make sense...the C# code the caption string is not interpolated...its just a string...equivalent code would instead be  just "caption:{$textToWrite}"

Comment: This line of C # code is turned into a PS script, a bit difficult, multiple attempts are not successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're seeing in the error is that you are using a Powershell interpolated string. It thinks you are injecting the variable "$caption" into the string.

This is because in Powershell, strings that are enclosed in double quotes `"` are treated as interpolated strings. Where as strings enclosed in single quotes `'` are treated as literal strings.

In C#, all strings are enclosed in double quotes. But if you want to use interpolated strings, then you preface it with a `$` sign, and then you inject your code by using {curly brackets}.

Powershell Example:

```
$name = "Chad"
Write-Host "Hello $name!" // Interpolated
Write-Host 'Hello $name!' // Literal
```

Powershell sees the double quotes, and knows to look for variable names inside of the string. In this case, it sees `$name` and swaps it out with its value. But when single quotes are used, it outputs the literal string.

C# example:

```cs
var name = "chad";
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}!"); // Interpolated
Console.WriteLine("Hello {name}!");  // Literal
```

Whereas in C#, this is how interpolated and literal strings work...

---

So you need to convert the C# interpolated string into a PowerShell interpolated string:

From (C#):

```cs
$"caption:{textToWrite}"
```

To (PowerShell):

```
"caption:$textToWrite"
```

Comment: The problem has been resolved,thanks`$caption = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage([string]::format("caption:$textToWrite"), $readSettings)`

Comment: Do you have a good perspective? 
 about using and new https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261346/conversion-using-and-new-key-in-powershell-for-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You can do it :

```
 $Arg1="caption:{0}" -f $textToWrite
 $caption = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage($Arg1, $readSettings)
```

Comment: also successfully execute, the same effects above,Do you have a good perspective? about using and new, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261346/conversion-using-and-new-key-in-powershell-for-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

$caption = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage([string]::format("$caption:{$textToWrite}"), $readSettings)

you are trying to define a variable...but in the constructor reference that same variable ($caption)that doesnt make sense

the C# code the caption string is not interpolated...its just a string...equivalent code would instead be  just "caption:$textToWrite"

```
 $caption = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage([string]::format("caption:$textToWrite"), $readSettings)
```

Comment: ERROR: Exception calling "Format" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: In the problem description, all related files have just been uploaded, wow,This line of code is converted into PS, quite difficult