# Convert C# `using` and `new` to PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, code-conversion

There are many codes in C# that use the keywords `using` and `new`. They look very simple!

How to achieve that in in PowerShell elegantly!

For example I want to change the following C# code to PowerShell

```
using (var image = new MagickImage(new MagickColor("#ff00ff"), 512, 128))
{
    new Drawables()
      // Draw text on the image
      .FontPointSize(72)
      .Font("Comic Sans")
      .StrokeColor(new MagickColor("yellow"))
      .FillColor(MagickColors.Orange)
      .TextAlignment(TextAlignment.Center)
      .Text(256, 64, "Magick.NET")
      // Add an ellipse
      .StrokeColor(new MagickColor(0, Quantum.Max, 0))
      .FillColor(MagickColors.SaddleBrown)
      .Ellipse(256, 96, 192, 8, 0, 360)
      .Draw(image);
}
```

It is difficult to write the `new` expression because it contains one another！ What elegant solution is there?

[image]

Comment: @Claies C# and PowerShell have many similarities. PS can use C# class library, but some places are not easy to convert, such as the above

Comment: @Claies both run on the .NET framework. Powershell can do everything other .NET languages like F#, C#, VB.NET... can and vice versa

Comment: Using the following tools, you can convert between C# and PowerShell, but the effect of complex code is not very good,https://ironmansoftware.com/powershell-pro-tools-powershell-module/

Answer (score 1):

C# `using` is just syntactic sugar for `try {} finally {}` so you can do the same in PowerShell. The disposal of the object will be put in the `finally` block. `new` can be replaced with `New-Object`. Of course `new` can be made an alias to `New-Object` but [MS chose not to](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/why-isnt-new-object-aliased-to-new/)

```
try {
    $color = New-Object MagickColor -ArgumentList (,"#ff00ff")
    $image = New-Object MagickImage -ArgumentList ($color, 512, 128)
    $drawable = New-Object Drawables
    $drawable.FontPointSize(72). `
              Font("Comic Sans"). `
              StrokeColor(New-Object MagickColor -ArgumentList (,"yellow")). `
              FillColor()...
}
finally {
    if ($image) { $image.Dispose() }
    # or just `$image?.Dispose()` in PowerShell 7.1+
}
```

See

- [About Try Catch Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.1)
- [using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: Thank you for your analysis of keyword【using】. Now, it is difficult to understand the keyword【new】 in the code above, because one contains another

Comment: @tianyi there's nothing special about those nested new. They're just R-Value Expressions that you can store in a variable (see my edit) or pass directly as arguments to other functions like this `$image = New-Object MagickImage -ArgumentList ((New-Object MagickColor -ArgumentList (,"#ff00ff")), 512, 128)`

Comment: .Font("Comic Sans") This should not be supported by powershell, Cannot start with.

Comment: @tianyi if `FontPointSize` returns a `Drawables` then obviously `.Font` will be called correctly. Functions and methods are called in powershell just like in C#. It's just that the new line ends the command so you need to escape it with backticks. See the updated code

Comment: @tianyi just found out that the [member access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#member-access-operator-) must immediately follow the object so just move the dot to the upper line

Comment: My system is win7 64 bit,Cannot support powershell7.1,The highest supported version is 5.1

Comment: In the problem description, I added the powershell code, and there are still some problems see pic https://i.ibb.co/267G9Yh/drr.png

Comment: @tianyi who said that the code must be run in powershell 7.1? Did you even look at my updated code above or just read the comments? You must **escape the new lines** exactly as how I do with the backticks